# setLayoutParams on ConstraintLayout does not change size

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

**Story**

I have 2 textviews, one on top of another:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX[TextView1]
XXXXXXXXXXXX[TextView2]
```

- Both TextViews aligns to the right. (Hence the XXX above)
- TextView1 has a background color.
- TextView2 is always longer than TextView1
- TextView1's left must be aligned with TextView2

I have the above 4 requirements. Now everything works well by using ConstraintLayout, where TextView1's left is constrained to TextView2's left, and TextView2's width is `wrap_content`.

But now it comes the 5th requirement:

- TextView2 can disappear, leaving TextView1 behind.

`setVisibility(GONE)` does not work, because TextView2 must be `wrap_content`. it will become 0 in width and therefore TextView1 as well (since its left is constrained to TextView2's left)

Then I tried to set TextView2's height to be 0, using the below code:

```
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)textView2.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = widthInPixelOrConstant;
    textView2.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Oops, nothing happens. TextView2 remains there, as if nothing happened.
I Googled for half an hour, and finally decided to wrap `TextView2` in a `LinearLayout`.

And then using the below code to set height of TextView2 to be 0:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams )view.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = widthInPixelOrConstant;
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

......It works!!!

**The Question**

So, apparently, we cannot use what we used before - `setLayoutParams` to try to alter the height or width of a ConstraintLayout's child at runtime.
But then, wrapping that TextView2 in a LinearLayout is really stupid.
Does anyone knows how to change a ConstraintLayout's child width or height at runtime?

Comment: Can you share whole layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try add constraints at runtime, like this:

```
//Define some variables
TextView textView1;
TextView textView2;
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;

//Initialize them, and so some stuff
textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);

int x = 200; //set some width
int y = 200; //Set some height        

ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

lp.width = x;
lp.height = y;

//moves TextView1's left to align with TextView2's left
lp.editorAbsoluteX = ((int) textView2.getX());     

textView1.setLayoutParams(lp);

ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);        

constraintSet.connect(R.id.text1,ConstraintSet.LEFT,R.id.text2,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
constraintSet.connect(R.id.text2,ConstraintSet.TOP,R.id.text1,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);

constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: This does not work for me... Not only the height does not change, the constraints are broken as well.

Comment: You can add constraints at runtime, and skip them in the layout xml, check my updated answer and see if there's something there which can help you.